# How to add html page into a flex web application

Tags: html, actionscript-3, apache-flex, web

How to add html page into a flex web application. My requirement is when a button is clicked i want a particular html page to open as popup. Is that possible in Flex Web application,

FYI, 
mx:HTML component is not supported in Flex Web Application,
StageWebView is also not supported in Flex Web Application.

I want dynamic Html content to display with in Flex(Web), Please guide me with possible solutions.

Comment: Use [StageWebView](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html)

Comment: use navigateToUrl or overlay an iframe

Comment: @Jason sturges, StageWebView not supported in web application,

Comment: Finally i managed it by using ExternalInterface to call a javascript function to overlay a iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RichText component

```
import flashx.textLayout.formats.WhiteSpaceCollapse;        
import spark.utils.TextFlowUtil;

protected function importRichText():void
{
    var richTextXML:XML =
        <TextFlow xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/textLayout/2008">
            <p fontSize="10">A small normal paragraph</p>
            <p fontSize="14" fontWeight="bold">
                A medium bold paragraph
            </p>
            <p fontSize="18">A large
                <span fontStyle="italic">mixed-text paragraph</span>
            </p>
        </TextFlow>

    myRichText.textFlow = TextFlowUtil.importFromXML(
        richTextXML, WhiteSpaceCollapse.PRESERVE);
}

protected function exportRichText():void
{
    var xmlText:XML = TextFlowUtil.export(myRichText.textFlow);
    myLabel.text = xmlText.toXMLString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use mx:Text component

```
<mx:Text id="myText" width="100%">
    <mx:htmlText>
         <![CDATA[This is <font color="#FF0000">HTML text</font> in a <b>Halo Text component</b>. Using the <u>htmlText attribute</u> of the <font color="#008800">Text component</font> you can use basic HTML markup.]]>
    </mx:htmlText>
</mx:Text>
```

or

```
myText.htmlText = "This is <font color='#FF0000'>HTML text</font> in a <b>Halo Text component</b>. Using the <u>htmlText attribute</u> of the <font color='#008800'>Text component</font> you can use basic HTML markup.";
```

Comment: Thanks anton, Can you please tell me how do get the content from any link ex: www.google.com

Comment: Sorry but I don't have any idea (( If you will find solution please write it in this topic

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting AIR (Adobe Integrated Runtime) instead of Web application, then, you can do this by using,

[HTMLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/html/HTMLLoader.html) (Air 1.0 or above)

`HtmlLoader` will work only on desktop air application. While `StageWebView` will work on desktop as well as mobile (android, ios etc) platforms.